# LINQ: check whether two list are the same

Tags: linq

This should be easy.

I want to check whether two list are the same in that they contain all the same elements or not, orders not important.

Duplicated elements are considered equal, i.e.e, `new[]{1,2,2}` is the same with `new[]{2,1}`

Comment: @280Z28: so you voted down a question because of the answers? Doesn't sound very reasonable.

Comment: The SetEquals of HashSet is best suited for checking whether two sets are equal as defined in this question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var same = list1.Except(list2).Count() == 0 && 
           list2.Except(list1).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: What is a differing duplicate?

Comment: An even more "linq-ish" version:  `!list1.Except(list2).Any() && !list2.Except(list1).Any()`

Comment: @TLS And it doesn't require counting all of the differences, just the first.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** This was written before the OP added that { 1, 2, 2 } equals { 1, 1, 2 } (regarding handling of duplicate entries).

This will work as long as the elements are comparable for order.

```
bool equal = list1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Comment: This wont help with duplicates.

Comment: @leppie: What do you mean? If `list1` contains 4 `3`, then `equal` would only be true if `list2` also contained exactly 4 `3`. Duplicates work fine.

Comment: You can take out the OrderBy calls if the order of the sequence will be the same; such as when you are comparing occurrence lists from tests.

Comment: @Jason: True, but the question explicitly states that you can't assume anything about the order of the elements.

Comment: And what about 3 elements vs 10 elements, all elements being 'a'.

Comment: @leppie: Then obviously the lists are not the same, and it returns the correct answer: false.

Comment: But they contain all the same elements, like the OP asked.

Comment: if you add a ".Distinct()" to list1 and list2, this will also handle duplicates and return the correct answer as the question desires.

Answer (score 4):

The [SetEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx) of [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is best suited for checking whether two sets are equal as defined in this question

```
        string stringA = "1,2,2";
        string stringB = "2,1";

        HashSet<string> setA = new HashSet<string>((stringA.Trim()).Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
        HashSet<string> setB = new HashSet<string>((stringB.Trim()).Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));

        bool isSetsEqual = setA.SetEquals(setB);
```

REFERENCE:

1. [Check whether two comma separated strings are equal (for Content set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630545/check-whether-two-comma-separated-strings-are-equal-for-content-set)

Comment: Using HashSets seems like the most elegant way to do this (and probably pretty fast too.)

Comment: Only if you rely on hash to be unique. I guess that with the right hash it will be unique for the numbers it can represent - but then it shouldn't be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the intersection of the two lists:

```
bool areIntersected = t1.Intersect(t2).Count() > 0;
```

In response to you're modified question:

```
bool areSameIntersection = t1.Except(t2).Count() == 0 && t2.Except(t1).Count() == 0;
```

Comment: I think my question is not phrased clearly... I've modified the question

Comment: If `t1` is { 1, 2, 2 } and `t2` is { 1, 2, 2 }, this will incorrectly return false.